# Firebase functions query db to see if username already exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase and Javascript so sorry if the answer is obvious.

I'm creating a function that imports a username, email, and password and checks if they are valid.
For the username one of the things I want to check is if there is already a user with the same name.
To see this I need to query my Firestore DB. The users are in the collection users with a doc for each user.
I don't know what to do.

This is what I have. (Only the relevant part of the code)

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

var db = admin.firestore();

exports.checkUserValid = functions.https.onCall((data) =>{

    const email = data.email;
    const username = data.username;
    const password = data.password;

    try {
    /*
    Rest of the function
    /*

    const snapshot = db.collection('users').where('username', '==', username).get();
        if(snapshot.size > 0){
          return {status: "failed", message: "Name already in use."};
        }
    
        return {status: "ok", message: "ok"};

}catch (error){
    console.log(error);
        return {status: "failed", message: "Server error. "+ error};
      }
```

I've tried multiple things but for some reason, it either tells me its ok or fails no matter the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.get()` return a Promise, So you will need to add `await` front of `.get()` to wait until data getting fetched, Or program will run next line without wait for data fetch.

```
// add async here
exports.checkUserValid = functions.https.onCall(async (data) =>{

    const email = data.email;
    const username = data.username;
    const password = data.password;

    try {
      // add await here
      const snapshot = await db.collection('users').where('username', '==', username).get();
      if(snapshot.size > 0){
        return {status: "failed", message: "Name already in use."};
      }
    
      return {status: "ok", message: "ok"};

    }catch (error){
      console.log(error);
      return {status: "failed", message: "Server error. "+ error};
    }
}
```